# Умные десятизначные числа

Tags: php

Добрый день, ребята подскажите реализацию функции умных десятичных чисел, простая реализация округлений не подходит так как цифры могу быть десятизначные а могут и не быть

задача такая что есть расчеты и может быть 
цифра

```
 1) 0,00025325
 2) 0,0000000225
 3) 0.02501
```

и мне нужно в каждом числе показать два символа после нулей,
к примеру:

```
0,00025 
0,000000022
0.025
```

как можно реализовать чтото подобное в одной функции ?

Как я вижу решение, но помоему функция сложновата и хотелось бы проще

```
 public static function numbersAfterDecimalPoint($number)
    {

        $number = number_format($number, 10, ',', ' ');
        $breakUpNumber = explode(",", $number);

        if(!isset($breakUpNumber[1])){
            return $number;
        }
        $lang = iconv_strlen($breakUpNumber[1]);
        $number = '';
        $counter = 0;
        for ($i = 0; $i < $lang; $i++){
           if($breakUpNumber[1][$i] == '0'){
               $number .=  $breakUpNumber[1][$i];
           }else{
               $number .= $breakUpNumber[1][$i];
               $counter++;
               if($counter == 2){
                   break;
               }
           }
        }
        if($counter == 0){
            return  number_format($number, 2, ',', ' ');
        }
        return  $breakUpNumber[0].','.$number;
    }
```

Comment: что вы уже попытались сделать?

Comment: да прикрепил свое решение

Comment: Зачем так извращаться, если есть регулярки?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
preg_replace('/([0-9]*)([.,])(0*)([1-9]{0,2}).*/', '$1$2$3$4', $myNumber);
```

Answer (score 1):

поскольку вы в своем решении работаете с числами как со строками, то можно просто использовать регулярные выражения

```
$data = [
     0.00025325,
     0.0000000225,
     0.02501,
     0.1
  ];

foreach($data as $d){
    $str = number_format(10, $d, ',', '') ;
    if(preg_match('/(\d+)[.,]0*(\d{1,2})/', $str, $matches)){
        print_r([$matches[0]]);
    }
}
```

---

Предложу еще математический вариант без регулярок (в данном случае, когда целая часть равна 0), но он не совсем точен, кажется.

```
foreach($data as $d){
    $l = log10($d);
    print_r([  number_format($d, -floor($l)+1, ',', '') ]);
}
```

Comment: в квадратных скобках не нужно экранировать точку

Comment: @rjhdby ага. но тут еще и другая проблема есть, длинное число записывается через `e`.

Comment: что решается предварительным форматированием через `number_format`, как и в вопросе автора.

Comment: да number_format пришлось использовать, спасибо

Comment: Ребята по этой функции возникла проблема , если приходит число 335,000000000 оно таким и остается , как то можно подкорректировать чтобы оставалось 335,00 в таких случаях ? 
использую   return preg_replace('/([0-9]*)([.,])(0*)([1-9]{0,2}).*/', '$1$2$3$4', number_format($number, 10, ',', ' '));

Answer (score 0):

у меня получилось таким способом

```
       return preg_replace('/([0-9]*)([.,])(0*)([1-9]{0,2}).*/', '$1$2$3$4', number_format($number, 10, ',', ' '));
```